# How to use script to build IntelliJ Idea project to a jar

Tags: intellij-idea, jar

i have created an IntelliJ Idea (Community Edition) java project. the project is quite simple. it only contains a main() method, but uses another 2 jars as dependencies. I also created an artifact to the project to build it to a jar.

My question is there any way to build the jar using script? because I want to add the build process to an existing build script.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDEA doesn't do anything with the code on its own, it just counts on the default tools provided by SDK. In short, you will need [javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) and [jar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/) for packaging.

Comment: could you give me a sample for this?

Comment: Just a few clicks in Google: [javac](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-use-the-javac-command.html) and [jar](http://www.codejava.net/java-core/tools/using-jar-command-examples)